# Parsing and pasting a variable in r

Tags: r, string, parsing, vector, paste

If I have a variable that contains a vector of strings like:

```
a <- c("apple", "pear", "orange", "kiwi")
```

How can I parse and paste it into a new variable called `b` that looks like this:

```
b <- c("\"apple\"", "\"pear\"", "\"orange\"", "\"kiwi\"")
```

I need it to be in this *odd* format in order to use it in the `sql` code for `read.csv.sql`.

Comment: `paste0("\"", a, "\"")` ?

Comment: [`dQuote(c("apple", "pear", "orange", "kiwi"))`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sQuote.html). If you're doing SQL work, consider using `DBI::dbQuoteString` instead (or [parameterized queries](https://xkcd.com/327/), even better).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of options:

```
a <- c("apple", "pear", "orange", "kiwi")

## Option 1
paste0('"', a, '"')
## [1] "\"apple\""  "\"pear\""   "\"orange\"" "\"kiwi\""  

## Option 2    
options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)
dQuote(a)
## [1] "\"apple\""  "\"pear\""   "\"orange\"" "\"kiwi\""
```

Comment: Can you tell why `paste0('"', a, '"')` works the way it does?

Comment: @markus  There are two pieces to that. First, R represents (prints) character strings as sequences of characters delimited by a double quotes. That explains why a double quote character appearing **within** a string is escaped, in its printed representation, like so: `\"`. Second, R allows users to **supply** character strings as sequences of characters delimited by either double quotes or single quotes. That's a minor convenience that allows you to avoid explicitly escaping quotes on input in a string that contains only single or double quotes.

Comment: @markus Honestly, the best way to understand this is to play around a bit with the different ways of passing in strings. For example: `"hi"; 'hi'; identical("hi", 'hi')`. And then perhaps: `a <- "I'm saying \"no\""; b <- 'I\'m saying "no"'; identical(a,b)`, etc...